# How to put the cursor on current highlighted file while in Xcode Navigation Panel using the keyboard

Tags: xcode

When navigating using up and down arrows in the navigation panel on Xcode I want to go to the file currently highlighted. If I press enter I just edit the name of the file.

From this, to actually navigating the file itself. Using only the keyboard.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some possible solutions :

Press control-` (backquote) to navigate to the next editor (which is probably the main editor).

Press Command-J to get a proposal (which is probably the main editor) and press Enter to confirm

Press command-1 to come back to the navigator

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. If you go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Key bindings and search for "Focus". A command like "Control + `" will work.
[image]